# Creating a git remote on a Windows network location using SourceTree: fatal: unable to get current working directory: No error

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-remote, sourcetree

I want to create a remote repo in a network place with Windows name `\\company.net\dumptruck\repos\MyRepo` by using SourceTree. I have read around but I haven't found a solution to my case. Here is what I have done.

1. I tried to open the terminal from SourceTree but it didn't open. This because I guess you need to create/clone a repo first.
2. Then I have tried to create a new repo through the SourceTree GUI by providing either `\\company.net\dumptruck\repos\` and `//company.net/dumptruck/repos/` as path. In both the cases I got the error `fatal: unable to get current working directory: No error`
3. I thought that it may be better to go with the Command Line. Therefore, I created a local repo in `C:\Somewhere\MyRepo` in order to be able to open the terminal. Then, I issued `cd //company.net/dumptruck/repos/` followed by `git init --bare`. I get the same error as before: `fatal: unable to get current working directory: No error` Note that I can reach the folder `//company.net/dumptruck/repos/`
4. Both the commands `pwd` and echo `$PWD` provide `//company/dumptruck/repos/`

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

I continue the discussion here since I am not allowed to write in the comments box (too many characters).

Both the commands `pwd` and `echo $PWD` provide `//company.net/dumptruck/repos/`. Sorry, my bad in my previous comment.

Nevertheless,  I tried to issue the following commands from GitForWindows and from the terminal provided by SourceTree (that should be MINGW32):

```
cd '//company.net/dumptruck/repos/'
git init --bare
```

In both the cases I got

```
error: unable to create directory for //company.net/dumptruck/repos/HEAD
```

I asked a colleague of mine to perform the same with his client (he uses Cygwin). Everything seemed to work smoothly.

In reality, I am allowed to clone the repo, but I am not allowed to push into it. I guess the problem may rely either on the permission or on the path. We adjust the permissions, but the problem was still there.

All the problems got solved by mapping the network location into a network drive. I personally don't like using network drives and I wonder if there is a way for making everything to work just by using network location names.

Comment: I had the same issue and it is also solved for me by ensuring that the remote/origin uses a mapped drive letter rather than UNC. This is not a SourceTree issue as the same thing happens with Git Bash for Windows, and the same solution applies. The local repository can always use a UNC path just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough rights to read and write to these directories?
You may have to run these as administrator.

Comment: In `//company.net/dumptruck/repos/` I can write whatever I want, so I assume I have the rights to read/write at least. However, if issue `cd ..` I get permission denied.

Comment: Sounds like the directory path may not be the actual directly rather a link to another directory. Like my documents vs documents. Are u issuing these commands on the actual server , I mean have u remoted to the server and running it on the actual server?

Comment: You mentioned //company/dumptruck/repos/ is returned when you do pwd. that is differnet from \\company.net\dumptruck\repos\ or //company.net/dumptruck/repos/.  Is \\company your server `name` ?

Comment: My bad. The correct in both cases is `//company.net/dumptruck/repos/`. However, due to lack of space, I continue this discussion in a new answer.